# requestAnimationFrame Parallax Scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, parallax, requestanimationframe

I'm building a site with parallax scrolling backgrounds similar to the spotify.com homepage. I'm using transform3d to move the images around and thought I'd wrap the animation in requestAnimationFrame for improved performance. Works great in Chrome but in Firefox I see some white flickering where the images are redrawing. In fact Firefox seems to work better when the animation is not in requestAnimationFrame. Does anyone know why this would be or how I can optimise further?

Here is a link to the source code:

http://codepen.io/fatlinesofcode/pen/xcnKh

And screenshot of bug.

[image: scroll bug]

Comment: Just for your notes, I have the same issue with chrome, and when I use the mouse wheel the entire image flickers white.